# Maven link compiled classes instead of a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am porting an existing project into maven project. I am stuck at following problem.

Our project uses a different team's compiled classes and till now we used to link those classes to our project by adding a class folder in eclipse. (Our application code imports these classes)

[image]

1. How can I do the same in maven?
2. Is there a way to port classpath entries from non-maven Java project to Java project?

The **other** team does not release jars. And their source is also not available. Only their compiled classes are available. Since it's location remains same.

I tried to use the `additionalClasspathElements` mentioned [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-failsafe-plugin-2.9/examples/additional-classpath.html), but still get compilation error for missing those classes.

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>Src/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>bin/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>            
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>D:/share/java</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: I have looked up how to create a local repo and that indeed is great for local jars. But problem in my case is exactly as you described. The other team updates classes and when we build the next time, we need to have the latest version of that class.

Comment: Comments moved to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Maven you will need to create a local Maven package containing the other team's classes in a jar file. You ***really*** want to do this so you are not building your code against a moving target every time the other team updates a class. Rebuild the jar for your team in coordination with the other team, at stable release points in the other team's development cycle.

If you need to pick up every change as it happens then you need to rebuild the package every time the other team changes a class. But that is very bad practice as you will build against unstable code, which is the situation you are in now.  What currently happens when the other team updates several classes *while your build is running*?  Does it break your build?  Using proper release management eliminates that problem, assuming only stable, tested builds are released.

Work on getting the other team to establish a real release process using Maven so they can provide stable releases to their clients (i.e., you). This is fundamental release management practice that should be a company standard.

Explaining how to do all this is beyond the scope of StackOverflow, find a tutorial on setting up a local Maven repo.

Comment: I understand that what you have described are the best practices. But I guess I failed to describe the exact problem.Let me try one more time.The changes in the other team's classes, are not very frequent and there is a proper flow to notify about the changes to all the clients. It's just that they do not provide a jar. If we keep the impact of changes aside for a moment, is there a way to include compiled classes in maven?